# Return a conditional TypeScript declaration from another function

Tags: typescript, types, createelement, conditional-types

**TypeScript** knows that `globalThis.document.createElement('img')` returns a type of `HTMLImageElement` based on the string `'img'` being passed into the function.

```js
const elem1 = globalThis.document.createElement('img');  //type: HTMLImageElement
console.log(elem1.constructor.name);  //'HTMLImageElement'
```

How would I capture that return type to be used in a wrapper function?

For example, what would the **TypeScript** declaration be for the `createElem` function below so that the `tag` parameter determines the correct return type?

```js
const createElem = (tag: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap) => {
   const elem = globalThis.document.createElement(tag);
   elem.dataset.created = String(Date.now());
   return elem;
   };

const elem2 = createElem('img');  //type: HTMLElement | ...68 more...
console.log(elem2.constructor.name);  //'HTMLImageElement'
```

A `tag` value of `’img’` should result in a `HTMLImageElement` type.  A `tag` value of `’p’` should result in a `HTMLParagraphElement` type and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the official type definition of `createElement` you will see:

```
createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(tagName: K, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K];
```

Let's apply the same logic to your function:

```
const createElem = <K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
  tag: K,
): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K] => {
  const elem = globalThis.document.createElement(tag);
  elem.dataset.created = String(Date.now());
  return elem;
};
```

Testing:

```
const elem2 = createElem('img');  // HTMLImageElement
const elem3 = createElem('p');  // HTMLParagraphElement
console.log(elem2.constructor.name);
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAJiYBXAtgUzFAOgEcMcAnATwGUcAbHYKEMgCgHIBLLAczYEoA3AFgAUKEixgZHHCg4AovSxIYAHgDSMHAA85YFBBgBrHBRAAzGAAkAKgFkAMopy58NuNwBycXHbgAHAD4WURgYKA8ALhh1ABpRPmjbR2dXKHcvHxw-fwBtdQBdJECYAG9QmHFoLSUVbloQACM4WhsACw4IAjRMNIIpGTlUvCgWCO5BCroXbtk4CBxCAdkcFBUqKDIOMG4WABEVgjAQAHcWPkmRMOkoDDIwGpdhEQBfZ9Eq2GmsACYVZaGSnYXF4gjCAHpwdZ7A4AJJYDwKJQjD7garfADM-2kK1S7H8-AEEKhyQcAAU4GQPFT-G1hvhUZAQPQCA1dt8fv00ZsMIxmEcspcgA)

Additionally, `createElement` supports passing any other strings as well, which is achieved using [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
    createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(tagName: K, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K];
    /** @deprecated */
    createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementDeprecatedTagNameMap>(tagName: K, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElementDeprecatedTagNameMap[K];
    createElement(tagName: string, options?: ElementCreationOptions): HTMLElement;
```

You can do the same thing for your function if you need that. Note that the order of overloads is important. The most defined one should come first. Which is `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap` in your case. The reason is typescript looks through the overloads from top to bottom and if you put the overload with `string` first then it would reach the `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach
just give your function the same type the function you want to wrap using `typeof`, then specify the parameters to be the same as the function you want to wrap using `Parameters` utility type.

```
const a = document.querySelector('img');
const createElem:typeof document.createElement = (
  ...args: Parameters<typeof document.createElement>
) => {
  const tag = args[0];
  const elem = globalThis.document.createElement(tag);
  elem.dataset.created = String(Date.now());
  return elem;
};

const elem2 = createElem('img');  // HTMLImageElement
const elem3 = createElem('p');  // HTMLParagraphElement
```

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAJiYBXAtgUzFAOgEcMcAnATwGUcAbHYKEMgCgHIBLLAczYEoA3AFgAUKEixgZHHCg4AovSwAuKBQAOOEADNU6bHkJSZcxTlz4kMFqJgwCDuGW4RlMAApO4uOWQgAeNU0dPUwLI2lZBSVDAD5RPiRYmABvWxhxaBgoOG4rJxcAbQAGAF1hETtM2DpzK25aEAAjOFoAFQALDggCNDDDAmMos3CWHO5BdNqsXtk4CBwIkxwUKyooMg4wbhYAESiCMBAAdxY+ScqYaSgMMjAYaYqAXwrRaoelACYrIdMldi4vEEdgA9CCYAAJNoAWQAMgBJLC5aLmQxvcBZaYAZh+kT+5nY6n4AlB4KhcM8ZFyVPUHRGaLEGJA9AIjR200+gwxGwwjGYh28OAuQA)

This also has the advantange of not having to declare the type again, which would be useful for this case since createElement has many overloads